# How can I remove one individual from a list of related dyads?

Tags: subset

I have a list of individual birds that are related to each other along a continuum from 0.0 (not related) to 1.0 (identical twins). At some threshold (say, 0.25) they are too related for downstream analysis and I want to remove one of them from the dataset. Sometimes, however, individuals are related to more than one other bird and in my dataset (~1700) this quickly gets complicated. Does anyone have code that would remove related individuals in a way that minimizes the losses from the dataset? In the following example data, Ind001 is related to Ind002 and and Ind004, but instead of removing both Ind002 and Ind004, I would like to remove just Ind001:

Example data:

```
pair.no ind1.id ind2.id relatedness
1038723 Ind001  Ind002  1.0
1038895 Ind001  Ind003  0.2
1280057 Ind001  Ind004  0.9
1389905 Ind002  Ind003  0.0
1390069 Ind002  Ind004  0.1
1390069 Ind003  Ind004  0.1
1390069 MNP002  MSW004  0.1
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

How about identifying the most related dyads, and then removing the one individual with the highest relatedness on average to everyone else, until you reach your threshold? Assuming data = what you provided above, one approach could be:

```
threshold = 0.25  #threshold for relatedness values
pruned_data = data

while(max(pruned_data$relatedness)>threshold){
  #find max relatedness estimate
  maxrelate = max(pruned_data$relatedness)

  #find records that are at the max relatedness
  temp = pruned_data[pruned_data$relatedness==maxrelate,,drop=FALSE]

  #find average relatedness for only those that are in the "max" group
  maxindvs = data.frame(id = unique(c(as.character(temp$ind1.id), as.character(temp$ind2.id))), 
                        mrelate = rep(0, length(unique(c(temp$ind1.id, temp$ind2.id)))))
  for(i in 1:nrow(maxindvs)){
    itemp = rbind(pruned_data[as.character(pruned_data$ind1.id)==maxindvs[i,1],,drop=FALSE],
                  pruned_data[as.character(pruned_data$ind2.id)==maxindvs[i,1],,drop=FALSE])
    maxindvs$mrelate[i] = mean(itemp$relatedness)
  }

  #remove individual that is most related to all others
  toremove = as.character(maxindvs[maxindvs$mrelate==max(maxindvs$mrelate),1])
  pruned_data = pruned_data[as.character(pruned_data$ind1.id)!=toremove & as.character(pruned_data$ind2.id)!=toremove,,drop=FALSE]
}
```